# Import python file to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

As a python file with the extension .py, has the code in lines like that

```
import requests
import hashlib

x=10
y=20
w=30

z=x+y

print(z)
```

As you notice there is an empty line in between each block. How to import such python code to Jupyter Notebook so as to make each block in a cell-like that
[image]

Comment: I couldn't get what you're looking for..?
Do you wanna merge all cells of jupyter notebook in one..?
You can do that by going in edit section of notebook or is there's something else ou looking for

Comment: I need simply to convert python code in a python file with .py extension TO jupyter notebook (making each block in a cell as I showed in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest parsing your *.py file and "manually" re-creating the *.ipynb file:

1. Distinguish blocks by separating the file at lines were only the `\n` is present;
2. Add lines of each block into:

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 5,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    # Here goes your lines
    "x = 2\n",
    "y = 3\n",
    ]
```

3. After put everything together:

```
}
"cells": [
  {# Block 1},
  {# Block 2},
  ...
  {# Block N},
]
}
```

#### Example

```
with open('py_file.py') as py_file:
    blocks = []
    next_block = []
    for line in py_file:
        if line == '\n':
            blocks.append(next_block)
            next_block = []
            pass
        else:
            next_block.append(line.strip())

cells = '''{\n  "cells": [\n'''
for i, block in enumerate(blocks):
    cells += '''  {\n   "cell_type": "code",\n'''
    cells += f'''    "execution_count": {i+1},\n'''
    cells += '''    "metadata": {},\n    "outputs": [],\n'''
    cells += '''    "source": [\n'''
    for line in block:
        cells += f'''    "{line}\\n",\n'''
    cells += '''    ]\n'''
    
cells += ' ]\n}'
```

`print(cells)` prints

```
{
  "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": 1,
    "metadata": {},
    "outputs": [],
    "source": [
    "import requests\n",
    "import hashlib\n",
    ]
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": 2,
    "metadata": {},
    "outputs": [],
    "source": [
    "x=10\n",
    "y=20\n",
    "w=30\n",
    ]
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": 3,
    "metadata": {},
    "outputs": [],
    "source": [
    "z=x+y\n",
    ]
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

> *Running code in terms on `cell mode` like in **Jupyter Notebook** by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can use `#%%` or `# %%`.*

**Code Syntax**

```
#%%
import requests
import hashlib
#%%
x=10
y=20
w=30
#%%
z=x+y
#%%
print(z)
```